# Localhost does not work on different computers but same network (Java sockets)

Tags: java, sockets, localhost, serversocket, connection-refused

This program normally works fine on different computers, but suddenly it started giving me the java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused, exception. Its the same network, and no problems if ran on the same computer. What to do?

The server:

```
    import java.io.*;  
    import java.net.*;  
    public class MyServer {  
        public static void main(String[] args){  
            try{  
                System.out.println("Server Running");
                ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(4242);  
                Socket s=ss.accept();  
                DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());  
                String  str=(String)dis.readUTF();  
                System.out.println("message= "+str);  
                ss.close();  
            }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}  
        }  
    }
```

The client:

```
import java.io.*;  
import java.net.*;  
public class MyClient {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        try{      
            Socket s=new Socket("localhost", 4242);  
            DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());  
            dout.writeUTF("Hello Server");  
            dout.flush();  
            dout.close();  
            s.close();  
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}  
    }  
}
```

Comment: `localhost` means the computer itself. It's like talking to a mirror. It is not the same of the computer. If you want the client to connect to *another* computer, then you need to specify the domain name or IP address of that computer *instead* of `localhost`.

Comment: Not enough details but I’m guessing you are getting this exception on the server side, and it’s probably because you have a running server already listening on the port. You can verify with netstat.

Comment: As mentioned by Andreas, if you’re trying to connect between two different computers localhost won’t work.